# What happend when I change the frame Of my view?

Tags: ios, frame

i want draw a wave line with 4500 points when the finger moves,but I don't want to make my view 4500 wide. 
In my limited experience , my idea is when the finger moves , increase width of the View and then draw the new increase rectangle use -setNeedsDisplayInRect:

```
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.size.width +=568;
        self.frame = frame;
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(568* self.currentPage, 0, 568, self.bounds.size.height)];
```

the result is :

[image: 1st pic]

But if i didn't change the frame of the view,it works fine:

[image: 2nd pic]

For this problem,I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.

What happened when I change the frame Of my view?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Instead, provide it as formatted text in your question, as a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This way, others can easily copy the code and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 CGRect frame = self.bounds;
```

instead of `CGRect frame = self.frame;`